# How do you run a docker containerized application behind an application gateway in Azure

Tags: api, azure, docker, spring-boot, api-gateway

I've been searching the help forums and the only documentation I've seen on how to do this is to create the gateway and then spin up vm's to run your application. We are using docker containers and I'm not sure of how to proceed. Additionally, is it possible to block off all access to applications behind a gateway and only have them be accessible through the gateway? Thanks a lot.